# pressing the run button to run a mojo file does nothing

Tags: visual-studio-code, mojolang

I'm trying to run mojo in VScode, however pressing the run button does absolutely nothing. No errors, no nothing.

I can run the file from terminal and it works fine but I would love to use running and debugging from VScode

I have installed mojo, the vscode mojo extension and Ive set the modular home path. Ive also verified that it is the correct path.

There seems to be nothing in the docs on this either. I don't use VScode frequently so I might just miss something very general here.

Is the functionality just not existent yet? If it is, what should I do to run or debug a mojo file within VS Code?

Kind regards

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwKwC.png)

go to Mojo Extension settings and fill Modular Home Path like this
i try this in windows vscode with WSL and worked but output of mojo code show in Mojo bash
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RorPj.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have said in my original post that I've already done this.